# How to organize a large project with solutions/projects/folders?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution

We are working on a very large VS project.

We want the project structure to "hint" developers on the logical components and design.

For this purpose, which is best:

1. One project with many subfolders and namespaces
2. Split to multiple projects based on logical grouping of classes. Have all projects in the same solution with solution folders.
3. Same as #2 but have multiple solutions instead of a single with subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My projects are huge.

We separate each "module" in different assemblies, creating Class Libraries. Something like this:

```
Client.ProjectName (Solution)
    Client (Class Library)
        - SectionHandler...
        - ComponentModels...
        - Utilities...

    Client.Web (Class Library)
        - Handelrs
        - Extenders

    Client.Net (Class Library)
        - MailQueue

    Client.Blog.WebControls.UI (Class Library)
        - TopContent.ascx
        - PostsList.ascx

    Client.News.WebControls.UI (Class Library)
        - TopContent.ascx
        - PostsList.ascx

    Client.Website
```

Each `Class Library` is a project under the solution `Client.ProjectName` or under some other shared solution.

The file system looks like this:

```
Client
|- Framework
   |- Client
      |- files...
   |- Client.Web
      |- files...
   |- Client.Net
      |- files...
|- SolutionName
   |- Client.Blog.WebControls.UI
   |- Client.News.WebControls.UI
   |- Website
```

Shared client libs goes immediately under the `Client\Framework` folder, it is meant to be used on all projects for this client. Specific projects goes under the solution. We also have a folder called `Company` where we keep projects that can be used in any other project for any client, it is like the company framework.

The solutions we use:

- One for the company framework
- One for a client framework
- One for each client solution

The same project can be referenced in multiple solutions, so you don't necessarily need to create all those solutions.

With this format we could use a lot of things on other projects simply referencing a DLL. Without this structure some projects wouldn't be possible in the given time.

Comment: how this maps to solutions / projects / folders?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are just containers for projects, so it's really the splitting of the projects that is in question.

I would recommend using a different project (AKA class library or assembly) for each major functional area.  You may still want to use different namespaces within each project, but separating the major functional areas into different assemblies will make each assembly smaller.  Therefore, if you need to use only one or two functions in an application, you only reference those two projects instead of the one massive project.  This will make for smaller applications that compile faster and have less overhead.

In terms of solutions, you can organize those however you want because like I said, they are only containers.  You may want to put them all in one solution...or maybe each in a separate solution...or maybe put related projects into solutions.  Personally, I either use one solution, or for large projects, I use a "master" solution so I can easily compile everything in one shot and individual solutions so I can work on projects individually.

Answer (score 1):

A project should be your "atom" of re-use.  Or to put it another way, projects are the granularity of reusable code.  It's OK to have interdependent projects but each project should be planned to be useful for its own functionality.

A solution is just whatever collection of projects you need for development / build / test.  You could have multiple solutions that specify different subsets of projects.

Folders within a project may help but they could be an indication that your project is getting too large.

Solution folders likewise mean your solution is probably getting too large.  Can you divide your codebase into multiple solutions, each with a meaningful and testable output artifact?  Solutions can depend on (tested) artifacts from other solutions, just as they do on third party libraries etc.

You should also consider how VS and solutions projects map to the granularity of projects on your version control schema and any branch/merge policies you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have grown to prefer a single solution with subfolders for the key domains, and add the projects in those. It's easy to browse, and gives a rough idea to your devs as to what goes where.

Having multiple solutions is mostly useful if the integrations between the components in eigther solution is loose, so each team has its work solution, and tests against released components from the other teams' solution.